# WooCommerce and ACF: How to Redirect Upon Add to Cart - Partially Working Example

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF on product pages to select a desired redirect URL after the product is added to the cart. Main use for this is to redirect to custom up sell pages.

Example: 
Product A has the ACF field "Redirect URL" populated with Product B. When Product A is added to cart, the user is redirected to Product B.

I have the following code in my functions.php:

```
function acf_product_redirect( $url ) {
    global $post; 

    if (get_field('redirect_url', $post->ID)) {
        $redirect_id = get_field('redirect_url', $post->ID); 
        $url = get_permalink($redirect_id);
        var_dump($url); // This $url var correctly displays my desired redirect URL
        return $url;    
    }


}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'acf_product_redirect' );
```

While viewing a single product page, var_dump($url) correctly displays the URL that I set on the product page. But... the redirect doesn't actually work.

If I move the 'return $url' line outside of the if statement and replace the $url variable with a static url, the redirect works.

So something is happening after I click Add to cart. That $url variable is not being passed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code. i have tested and it is working fine for me.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'acf_product_redirect' );
function acf_product_redirect() {
    #Get product ID
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ||  is_numeric( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
        $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
        # Check if redirect url set or not
        if (!empty(get_field('redirect_url', $product_id))) {
            $redirect_id = get_field('redirect_url', $product_id); 
            return get_permalink($redirect_id);
        }   
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That works! So it must be the difference in how we were both getting the product ID.

Really appreciate you providing the solution.